# Drag and drop dialog box

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, stackblitz

I am trying to make a dialog box window draggle with `cdkDrag` directive, currently only the content inside the dialog is movable. How it is possible to move the whole window?
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7e1fk9?file=src/app/dialog-overview-example-dialog.html)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `cdkDragRootElement` directive with selector mentioned inside the attribute value from where you want to enable the dragging element. Adding selector `.cdk-overlay-pane` makes sure the complete dialog is getting dragged. Along with that `cdkDragHandle` directive.

```
<div cdkDrag cdkDragRootElement=".cdk-overlay-pane" class="the_dialog" cdkDragHandle>
   ...
   ...
</div>
```

Just one suggestion, if you attached `cdkDrag` to the parent element, it will move the complete dialog box by clicking anywhere on the dialog box. Better just bind that event on mat-dialog-title should be great, in terms of UX.

**Restructured HTML**

```
<h1
  mat-dialog-title
  cdkDrag
  cdkDragRootElement=".cdk-overlay-pane"
  cdkDragHandle
>
  Hi
</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content class="the_dialog">
  <p>Move me around</p>
  Test here
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="data.animal" cdkFocusInitial>
    Ok
  </button>
</div>
```

[**Stackblitz Here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7e1fk9-zipjgt)

Comment: Works perfect!!